# MYOB AccountRight endpoint gives 596 Service Not Found

Tags: myob

I am trying to retrieve data from a dummy company using the AccountRight API.

I am building on [this nodejs sample project](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/myob_accountright_sample_nodejs).

Authentication and getting the company file from the company file work.

However, when I try to retrieve data for other endpoints such as [`/GeneralLedger/Account`](http://developer.myob.com/api/accountright/v2/generalledger/account/) I always get a `596 Service Not Found`.  My uri is:

`api.myob.com/<company id>/GeneralLedger/Account`

where the company id is the id I retrieve using the `/accountright` endpoint for the dummy company.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is incorrect meaning the API doesn't know you are talking to our AccountRight service.

The API is a hypermedia API and includes all the URIs you need ... however if you are constructing URI they should look like:
https://api.myob.com/AccountRight/{CompanyFile-GUID}/GeneralLedger/Account

Make sure /AccountRight/ is in the URL.

Comment: Ah, so I should just GET from https://api.myob.com/accountright and see what URI's are available?

Comment: Yes you can do that :)